# How does the kippah stay on the head?

Tags: kippa-yarmulka

I was just watching a video and noticed that the kippah is worn very far back - how doesn’t it fall off?

[image]

Apologies for such a probably “obvious” answer to anyone Jewish. I did search on the site and the question hadn’t been asked before; and I was kind of curious!

Comment: I'm Jewish myself and wear a Kippah and I still have that question regarding the above photo. Bennet's kippah is kinda small, and is precariously placed. So how it stays put is a mystery to me as well.

Comment: https://www.timesofisrael.com/from-bubblegum-to-magic-tape-how-bennetts-kippa-stays-on-and-why-it-matters/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! If you have relatively short hair and a kippah that fits well, the hair sort of grips the kippah to keep it in place. Otherwise, you have to use pins or clips.

Comment: or velcro, gravity or even certain tape (for bald people).

Comment: gravity works if you aren't exercising.

Comment: Bennet uses tape

Comment: Don't people know that all Jews have a magnet on top of their heads? And all kippot have an invisible magnet? Seriously, bobby pins and clips are probably the most common tools to hold down the kippah. However, even completely bald people can manage to keep a kippa on their head with no tools depending on the size of the kippah (bigger ones tend to "mold" and curve a bit more) and the kippah material. Some materials, I guess wool, e.g. create "static" which will make it more likely to stick. Other materials are "hotter" and stick to a bald sweaty head. Such, I have heard from a few bald people

Comment: I've read that bennet has used gum

Comment: I use thumbtacks, personally.

Comment: or crazy glue..